# Get url from origin in Blazor iframe

Tags: iframe, blazor

I am hosting a website which is made in Blazor as an iframe on multiple websites. Now I wanted to know the url from the hosting website within the iframe.

[I actually want to have the yellow urls in this picture to be exactly the same.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rI5I1.png)

In the image I used `NavigationManager.Uri` but this one gives me the url of the iframe and not the hosted website.

I also tried calling `window.parent.location.href` but then I got the exception:

> `Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://localhost:44304" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

How do I get this url using Blazor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general way to do that would be JS, as you tried. The fact that you get this exception indicates that the two origins (the main browser and your iframe-d app) are on different domains and so the browser will never let you do that - it's a security feature that prevents malicious iframes from hijacking the browser.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that it is never possible to get this url when my iframe is served from a different domain?

Comment: Yes. Look up the browser same-origin policy to see what you can access -cookies, JS,...
In your case, if you have some control over how your blazor app is embedded, maybe a queystring argument to the src of the iframe can be added, and you could read that through the NavigationManager in your blazor app where needed